# Yahoo Mail JSON API Invalid JSON

Tags: json, api, yahoo, scribe

I am trying to use Java Scribe Library to integrate with Yahoo Web Service. I was able to get the OAuth Integration done.

Now I am trying to call the ListMessages JSON API using sample request in here http://developer.yahoo.com/mail/docs/user_guide/JSON-RPCEndpoint.html#

My code looks like this:

```
Token requestToken = buildTokenFromDB();
OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder().provider(YahooApi.class).apiKey(API_KEY).apiSecret(API_SECRET).build();
 OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET,
                "http://mail.yahooapis.com/ws/mail/v1.1/jsonrpc");
String str = getFilesAsString("msg.json");
request.addPayload(str);            
request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");            
service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
Response response = request.send();
```

I am getting the following error:

{"result":null,"error":{"code":"Client.InvalidRequest","message":"Invalid Json.","detail":null}}

Looks like I can only use GET, but I am not sure if I need to use some param for payload or scribe does it automatically.
Thanks.
Geeth

Comment: Try using POST instead of GET, JSON-RPC is POST based =)

Comment: Thanks man. When I tried POST earlier, was getting some issues, but it seems ok now after adding headers

Comment: hi could you share your solution?

Comment: @kitokid  Changing from GET to POST worked for me. I based my code on this [link]https://raw.github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/master/src/test/java/org/scribe/examples/YahooExample.java and changed from GET to POST for the API call